# No value given for one or more required parameters. asp.net

Tags: asp.net, parameters, oledb

i'm having error: No value given for one or more required parameters. when click the enter button

```
 Protected Sub btnOrder_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOrder.Click


    Dim rentid As String = txtRentID.Text
    Dim memberid As String = lblMemberID.Text
    Dim items2 As String = DropDownList1.Text
    Dim date2 As Date = lblDate.Text
    Dim qty2 As Integer = CInt(txtQty.Text)
    Try
        Dim dbconn1, dbcomm1, dbex1, sql1
        dbconn1 = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/aspDB.mdb"))
        dbconn1.open()
        sql1 = "Insert into [Order] VALUES ( " & "'" & rentid & "'" & "," & "'" & qty2 & "'" & "," & "'" & date2 & "'" & "," & "'" & memberid & "'" & "," & items2 & ")"
        dbcomm1 = New OleDbCommand(sql1, dbconn1)
        dbex1 = dbcomm1.executenonquery
        lblOut.Text = "saved"
        dbconn1.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        lblOut.Text = ex.Message
    End Try


End Sub
```

is there any missing code? thanks for helping me

Comment: Just a note, you are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection attacks with this code. Consider altering this to use a parameterised query.

Comment: Also: this would help avoid problems such as forgetting to put quote marks around fields such as `items2`, which may be the cause of the problem.